# Proving products from a subset of a group are disjoint from products of a superset

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, permutations

Suppose $G$ is a *non-commutative* infinite group (e.g. $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$), and let $B \subset A \subset G$ with $A$ finite, and $|B|=m<|A|=n$.  In addition, suppose no element $g \in A$ is the identity, and no element in $A$ is the inverse of another element in $A$.

My question is as follows.  Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the set of all $n!$ products of all $n$ elements of $A$, and let $\mathcal{B}$ be the set of all $m!$ products of all $m$ elements of $B$.  Then is it always true that $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \emptyset$? And if not, what conditions must be placed on $A$ and $B$ such that $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \emptyset$?

Alternatively, what of the weaker question: do there exist such sets $A$ and $B$ such that $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \emptyset$? If so how many?

Comment: Suppose $B$ is chosen. Let $g_1,g_2,g_3$ be three non-identity elements of $G$, none of which are in $B$, for which $g_1g_2g_3=1$. Letting $A=B\cup \{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$ gives a counter-example. I suspect you wanted this result to apply to some other problem, and you would be better off asking about the other problem directly.

Comment: @MikeEarnest thanks, and this is actually not going to apply to any other problem, I am just curious.  But as I think about this more I suppose I could instead word it as an existence problem: do there exist subsets $A$ and $B$ such that $\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}=\emptyset$?  Indeed I am not really sure how to even prove this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike Earnest has already provided a counterexample to your first question, so I will address the question of existence.

We claim that such subsets $A, B$ exist for any infinite nonabelian group $G$. Let $x \in G$ be an arbitrary nonidentity element. Let $X = \{e, x^{-1}, x^{-2}\} \subset G.$ Since $G$ is infinite, $G \setminus X$ is clearly nonempty, hence there exists some $y \in G \setminus X.$ It is clear that $y$ is a nonidentity element of $G$ such that $y$ is not the inverse of $x$ or the inverse of $x^{2}$.

Let $A =  \{x, xy\},$ and $B = \{x\} \subset A.$ It is clear that $A$ does not contain the identity. Furthermore, if $x \cdot xy = e,$ then $y$ would be the inverse of $x^{2}$, contradiction. Therefore, no element of $A$ is the inverse of another.

Then, we see that $\mathcal{B} = \{x\},$ while $\mathcal{A} = \{x^{2}y, xyx\}$. If $x = x^{2}y,$ then we would have $e = xy,$ contradicting that $y$ is not the inverse of $x.$ If $x = xyx,$ we would have $e = xy,$ once again a contradiction. Therefore, we see that $\mathcal{A} \cap \mathcal{B} = \emptyset.$